# Text Field inside UICollectionViewCell Reusing Text

Tags: swift, swift2, cell, textfield, uicollectionviewcell

Can anyone provide assistance for using a text field inside a UiCollectionView. What I'm trying to accomplish is a collection view that holds images for a user to post. With these images I'd like to give them the chance to caption each individual image. The issue that I'm having, which I'm certain other's are having is this; once a user types in a text field the input automatically fills a text field later on.

Example: 5 Images with text fields.

Image 1's caption user types "hello"

Image 2's caption user types "there"

Image 3's caption user types "how are you"

Before user types anything in the text field for Image 4 it would read "Hello"

I've found one posting on stack to be beneficial but I'm still not comprehending what I'm suppose to be doing. I followed the suggested steps; 
1. creating an array to hold the text view inputs
2. In "textFieldDidEndEditing" method adding the current textfields input into the array if it's not empty.
Where I get confused is step 3, @bhanu suggests "the textfield value should entered from array and it won't misplace value."

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to store the array of textfield inputs, you are actually halfway there. But there is still some logic missing to make sure your textfield displays proper values instead of recycled text. You will have to store their `NSIndexPath` as well. Otherwise, how will you know which cell the textfield input belongs to?

```
var textInputs = [String]()
var textFieldIndexPath = [NSIndexPath]()

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {

// store the textfield.text into "textInput" array
// you might need to find a way to store NSIndexPath of the selected cell // into "textFieldIndexPath" array here. From the textField instance, you should be able to trace the NSIndexPath of the cell it belongs to 

}
```

Then, in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollViewCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell

 if textFieldIndexPath.contains(indexPath){
  cell.textField.text = textInput[indexPath.row]
 }
}
```

Bear in mind that what I wrote is just a rough guideline on how to solve your question. Ultimately, you should refine this set of codes as it is rigid and may be prone to bugs/loopholes. But I do hope it gave you some idea on how to go around this.

I would suggest using an array of `Tuples` instead of maintaining two arrays though to provide more flexibility.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This looks alot cleaner than the logic I was using. My solution ended up being me using a  dictionary

Comment: Glad I was able to help. My codeset is crude and might produce some bugs as it relies heavily on both arrays being in sync. So it would be best if you can just take some hints from it and refine it with something a little cleaner, like I suggested, array of Tuples or if you can work around with Dictionaries, would be good too